# How to find the Period and Phase angle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm currently brushing up my trig and found these two problems. I'm totally clueless on how to start. Please help.

Find the period , amplitude , and phase angle, and use these to sketch

a) $$3\sin(2x − π)$$

b) $$−4\cos(x + π/2)$$

Comment: First: do you know the addition formulae for $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Comment: you mean sin(A+B) = sinAcosB + cosAsinB and cos(A+B) = cosAcosB - sinAsinB right?

Comment: Yes, precisely. You also know the special values, e.g. $\sin\,\pi$ and $\cos\,\frac{\pi}{2}$ right?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response.$$sin{\pi} = 0$$ and $$cos{\pi/2}= 0$$

Comment: well what jm meant was to use these values and the addition formulae to see if u can arrive at the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In simple words. When talking about a periodic function:

- Amplitude is its highest absolute value. Well it's actually a subject to convention/definition what is called the amplitude, but at least for *sin/cos* functions this is so.
- Period is the **minimal** value that you may add to the argument without the function change.
- Phase is a matter of the convention. You may define one function as one with phase=0. Then if another function may be brought to this one by "shifting" (i.e. subtracting the shift from argument) - its *phase* is said to be equal to this shift.

Whereas the period has a strict absolute definition, the amplitude and the phase are subject for the convention. There is however a strict definition for relative amplitude and phase.

Now, about your exercise.

If you have a function of the form f(x) = |a| sin (bx + c) then:

- |a| is the amplitude
- 2π/b is the period
- c is the phase

Note: we actually defined a convention here. The amplitude is the maximum value of the function, and the phase=0 is defined for the point where the function is 0 with positive derivative.

f(x) = 3sin(2x−π) = 3sin(2x+π)

- Amplitude = 3
- Period = π
- Phase = π

f(x) = −4cos(x+π/2) = 4sin(x) [trigonometry equality]

- Amplitude = 4
- Period = 2π
- Phase = 0

Comment: My sincere appologies for the delayed response.The internet was down in my locality!!